# Collections of vectors with a small scalar product

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, combinatorial-optimization

Consider $m$ unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with positive coordinates so that $m>n$. How does one pick the $m$ unit vectors so that the largest inner product of them is the smallest?

Comment: It is equivalent to placing $m$ points on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ so that the minimal distance between them is a maximal. This have been studied a lot. Only in few cases the complete answer is known.

Comment: Dear Fedor Petrov, 

thank you for the information. Maybe there is a standard reference or paper that deals with this problem?

Comment: One reference, which also discusses a lot of related problems, is https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607446v2.pdf.